# Set Discord User to AFK in python

Tags: python, token, bots, discord

i have a discord bot written in python and it uses a users discord auth token. When th program is running it wont send any mobile notifications because it makes discord think im online and wont go afk for the afk timer to kick on. Is  there a way to use the auth token and not have discord think im logged in? or is there a way to make discord think the user is afk? any help would be gratly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Client.change_presence()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_presence)

```
await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.idle)
```

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Status) are the different kinds of `Status` available.

Comment: i pasted the code to a google doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zf9GVj6GXLi3miUXdMfa9ogzeb1WE1BeT1cD48obf7E/edit?usp=sharing

if you wouldnt mide taking a quick look, im not sure where to exactly put that. i used the offline status and put it under the ready_on and it didnt do anything. thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: so i figured it out and was able to change the bot status but the notifications still dont get pushed until i stop the program. any other thoughts?